# Detached DOM error in cypress while interacting with text field

Tags: angular, testing, cypress

I am interacting with mat input field using cypress and built an application using angular.
How to avoid **Detached DOM error** on cy.type('some text') which is coming even after should('is.visible') assertion has passed already ?
I have gone through the best treatment of Detached DOM error using cypress [Detached DOM Link](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/07/22/do-not-get-too-detached/).
The error text suggested to add guards to remove flake which I have placed also.
The content on net is also only about the select() call but I am facing it on .type()

So how to avoid this kind of Detached DOM error in cypress tests while using cy.type().

Comment: please post your code snippet.

Comment: Can you post your code?